# How to read contacts info from database

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I just want to read all contacts info in to a `PhoneBookBean`.

`PhoneBookBean` is include **first_name, lastname, email_address**. But it seems very difficult read like `People.URL`.

Using `ContactsContract`, it always need `mime_type` and must provide `lookupKey`, But i just need to iterate all contacts entry one person by one person.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
getContactInfo(intent);




    protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
    {
       Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {           
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))


               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {

                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            }
            phones.close();
           }

           // Find Email Addresses
           Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null);
           while (emails.moveToNext()) 
           {
            String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
           }
           emails.close();

        Cursor address = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                    null, null);
        while (address.moveToNext()) 
        { 
          // These are all private class variables, don't forget to create them.
             String poBox      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
             String street     = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
             String city       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
             String state      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
             String postalCode = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
             String country    = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
String  type   = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
        }  //address.moveToNext()   
      }  //while (cursor.moveToNext())        
       cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If intent is instantiate in method, why we have to set a intent parameter.thx

Comment: what is the value we get when call intent.getData()

Comment: I just paste the code at the beginning of the method.Actually intent is created in another method and then passed to this method.I paste it here so that you understand what it means.And intent.getData() this actually fetches the data

Comment: So one while loop get all the info listed? Because when i use ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI instead intent.getData(), only get one MIME_TYPE data.For example, i can only get phone number or email address in one while loop.

Comment: For one id,you can have multiple phone,email.So inner loop are used